# Single click forces the event to fire twice (possible problem in Webpack)

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am new to Webpack and not so experienced in JavaScript either. I'm trying to set up a new project for the JS text editor. However, I noticed that after setting up the first addEventListener for the #btn button, the event gets fired twice.

I don't think that this behaviour is related to the event itself, since I have created three console.log functions. One is outside the eventListener, two remaining is inside. All of the three functions get console logged twice in the browsers console, which leads me to think that this might be related to Webpack config.

If anyone has a clue or and advice, please help.

HTML:

```
<main class="main__content">
  <article class="text__editor-wrapper">
    <h1 class=" ">Text Editor</h1>
    <div class="toolbar">
     <button id="btn" class="toolbar__option"><span class="fas fa-bold fa-2x"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="text__editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
  </article>
</main>
```

index.js:

```
import "./scss/style.scss";
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js';

const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

function format(command, value) {
  document.execCommand(command, false, value);
}

console.log("Outside")
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("inside");
  console.log(e.target);
  format('bold');
});
```

webpack config file:

```
const path = require("path"),
  HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin"),
  BrowserSyncPlugin = require("browser-sync-webpack-plugin"),
  MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin"),
  UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  optimization: {
     minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    port: 900
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "file-loader"
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "url-loader"
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "sass-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: You'd be able to troubleshoot it from the packed code... index.js seems to be inserted twice? Are both console logs from the exact same trace? replace .log with .trace

Comment: And try building it without uglify and examine the bundle - that way you may be able to see if index.js is included multiple times

Comment: I commented out the Uglify plugin, but I still get the console.log functions outputed twice.
I console.trace("inside") inside the event and the result that I get is:

inside VM43666 index.js:35 
eval @ VM43666 index.js:35

inside  index.js:35 
eval @ index.js:35
So, I'm really confused about what is happening here, since I don't know Webpack that well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't given us your full HTML file, but I suspect this is where the problem lies.

Check your final (post-Webpack) index.html file - I suspect you're importing the `main.js` bundle in a `<script>` tag and also including the bundled JS.

This is because you're using Webpack to bundle your HTML (the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` plugin) and also creating a bundle (`main.js`) which you're importing somewhere in your HTML.

Comment: You're right. I just peeked at my index.html file in the dist folder and I see that it generated 2 <script src="main.js"></script><script src="main.js"></script> tags. But why is this happening? What should I change in webpack.config.js?

Comment: Ok. That's solved now. I have accidentally included main.js in the src/index.html.
Thank you very much for help!